# Integration with limits of a dataframe column

Tags: pandas, scipy, quad

Attempting to solve an integral using scipy quad to solve for the following:

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMKbE.png)

I have a dataframe with a column of U/U<sub>delta</sub> and when trying to apply

```
delta_115 = 3.41
def d_star_integrand_115(y, df_115, delta_115):
    return 1 - df_115['u/u_delta']


d_star_115, error_115 = quad(d_star_integrand_115, 
    0, delta_115, args=(df_115['u/u_delta'], delta_115)
```

Could anyone let me know if you can even do an integral of a vectorised column in python or if that is not possible?

Have attempted multiple different options for the integrand, however all lead to the same error:

KeyError: 'u/u_delta'

[Full traceback of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wu0L.png)

For reference the entire dataframe looks like this:

[df_115](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4dim.png)

Comment: The keyerror indicates it can't find the column as indicated by `df_115['u/u_delta']`.  I see something like that in the image, but what is the image - the dataframe itself, or a csv or other?  You may need to show us the actual error with  traceback.  and/or test one or more of the suspected operations, such as column selection.  In other words - basic debugging steps to isolate the problem.

Comment: the image is of the dataframe being printed (just using library called tabulate to display better). The column exists (result of df_115.columns is  Index(['y_m(mm)', 'h_box(mmH20)', 'h_pitot(mmH20)', 'h_open(mmH20)', 'y(mm)',
       'delta_h', 'dyna_pressure', 'U_air(m/s)', 'Re_115', 'u/u_delta', 'eta',
       'power_law_u/u_delta'],
      dtype='object').


I will edit the question and add the traceback of the error

Comment: Look carefully at the traceback.  The error occurs in `d_star_integrand_115`.  You've already selected the column.  Use a different argument name in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback says the keyerror is in `d_star_integrand_115`. The column indexing works ok in the `quad` call, but shouldn't be done again.

Corrected function

```
delta_115 = 3.41
def d_star_integrand_115(y, arg1, delta_115):
    return 1 - arg1  # arg1 is already a column


d_star_115, error_115 = quad(d_star_integrand_115, 
    0, delta_115, args=(df_115['u/u_delta'], delta_115)
```